# Using autograd to compute Jacobian matrix of outputs with respect to inputs

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I apologize if this question is obvious or trivial. I am very new to pytorch and I am trying to understand the autograd.grad function in pytorch. I have a neural network G that takes in inputs (x,t) and outputs (u,v). Here is the code for G:

```py
class GeneratorNet(torch.nn.Module):
    """
    A three hidden-layer generative neural network
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(GeneratorNet, self).__init__()
        self.hidden0 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2, 100),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)
            )

        self.hidden1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(100, 100),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)
            )

        self.hidden2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(100, 100),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)
            )

        self.out = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(100, 2),
            nn.Tanh()
            )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.hidden0(x)
        x = self.hidden1(x)
        x = self.hidden2(x)
        x = self.out(x)
        return x
```

Or simply G(x,t) = (u(x,t), v(x,t)) where u(x,t) and v(x,t) are scalar valued. Goal: Compute $\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}$. At every training step, I have a minibatch of size $100$ so u(x,t) is a [100,1] tensor. Here is my attempt to compute the partial derivatives, where coords is the input (x,t) and just like below I added the `requires_grad_(True)` flag to the coords as well:

```py
tensor = GeneratorNet(coords)
tensor.requires_grad_(True)
u, v = torch.split(tensor, 1, dim=1)
du = autograd.grad(u, coords, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u), create_graph=True, 
                   retain_graph=True, only_inputs=True, allow_unused=True)[0]
```

du is now a [100,2] tensor. 
**Question**: Is this the tensor of the partials for the 100 input points of the minibatch?

There are similar questions like computing derivatives of the output with respect to inputs but I could not really figure out what's going on. I apologize once again if this is already answered or trivial. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted should give you the partial derivative of your first output w.r.t. the input. However, you also have to set `requires_grad_(True)` on the inputs, as otherwise PyTorch does not build up the computation graph starting at the input and thus it cannot compute the gradient for them.

This version of your code example computes `du` and `dv`:

```py
net = GeneratorNet()
coords = torch.randn(10, 2)
coords.requires_grad = True
tensor = net(coords)
u, v = torch.split(tensor, 1, dim=1)
du = torch.autograd.grad(u, coords, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u))[0]
dv = torch.autograd.grad(v, coords, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(v))[0]
```

You can also compute the partial derivative for a single output:

```py
net = GeneratorNet()
coords = torch.randn(10, 2)
coords.requires_grad = True
tensor = net(coords)
u, v = torch.split(tensor, 1, dim=1)
du_0 = torch.autograd.grad(u[0], coords)[0]
```

where `du_0 == du[0]`.